# Django auth_view and generic class-based views

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-generic-views, change-password

Is it safe to code against django's auth_view for password_change or is there any class-based view that I can use?

I am converting all my function based views to class based views, but I have coded against django's auth_view that is not class based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your updated question about whether Django will support class-based auth views in the core: based on what I can see in [Django trunk](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/views.py) (1.4 should be released soon), the answer is "no, not anytime soon."

There is one project that I've found that has a provides some class-based views for authentication.

**[django-class-based-auth-views](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-class-based-auth-views/)**

It only has the login view at the moment, though.

*Update: Myself and my employer have released a packaged called [django-sky-visitor](https://github.com/concentricsky/django-sky-visitor) that has some class based authentication views in it that might be helpful here.*

Comment: auth_view in django is still function based. I need to know if that will be changed to class based or remain the same.

Comment: Perhaps you can look at [the main question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046659) which is the root cause of this question.

Comment: Are you asking if Django core is planning on upgrading the auth views to be class-based? My guess is not anytime soon. [Django trunk currently](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/views.py) doesn't have any class-based views for auth.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect your real question if you want to accept it for future-posters benefit.